# Selecting key from parameterized helper fails

Tags: meteor, helper, meteor-blaze

I would like to pass parameters to helper in Meteor as described [here](http://dev4devs.com/2015/07/17/meteor-js-how-to-pass-parameters-to-helpers-functions/)

I create a select element with names of teams which are playing together:

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="gameSelector" disabled="{{gamesSelectDisable}}">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled hidden>Select game</option>
  {{#each games}}
    <option value="{{this._id}}">
      {{teamById.name this.homeTeam}} x {{teamById.name this.guestTeam}}
    </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

My helpers looks like:

```
games: function(){
  return = GamesCollection.find({'playedInDivision' : Session.get('selectedDivisionId')});
},
teamById: function(teamId){
  return = TeamsCollection.findOne({'_id': teamId});
}
```

When I do:

```
console.log('team ID', teamId, this);
```

I get undefined and this object which corresponds to the *games* object. I get *undefined* even if I pass strings like

```
{{teamById.name "Some String"}}
```

Comment: make sure your subscription is working

Comment: I did not yet remove the autopublish package yet. Is this a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried getting a key from an object directly in a parameterized helper like that. What I would normally do is use `{{#with }}` to establish a data context (a new *this* essentially) and then use the keys directly.

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="gameSelector" disabled="{{gamesSelectDisable}}">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled hidden>Select game</option>
  {{#each games}}
    <option value="{{this._id}}">
      {{#with teamById this.homeTeam}}
        {{name}} x
      {{/with}}
      {{#with teamById this.guestTeam}}
        {{name}}
      {{/with}}
    </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Comment: This is actually exactly the solution I ended up with. I found it less elegant and I also read somewhere, that using {{#with}} is more of an workaround for passing parameters to helpers. That is why I search for other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Floyd for pointing me to the right direction. The problem lies in the dot notation used to access the team name. I came with slight different solution by making my helper function parameterized.

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="gameSelector" disabled="{{gamesSelectDisable}}">
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled hidden>Select game</option>
        {{#each games}}
          <option value="{{this._id}}">
              {{teamById this.homeTeam "name"}} x {{teamById this.guestTeam "name"}}
          </option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
```

The helper returns an object or just a relevant part of it depending on the passed parameter.

```
teamById: function(teamId, param){
var team = TeamsCollection.findOne({'_id': teamId});
if (param && param in team){
  return team[param];
}
else {
  return team;
}
```

},